# Why Wireless mouse and Wireless keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-networking, mouse

I still don't get why people want Wireless stuff. It's a little bit more pratical, but a lot less comfortable to work with : the mouses are far heavier because of the batteries, they are to the least **10 times less sensitive** and as for the keyboard, try to play games like Trackmania with a USB2.0 keyboard and with a wireless keyboard... I guess you'll quickly notice the **huge** difference... not to speak about the times when your keyboard batteries are empty and your keyboard works once each other key you press...

It seems there's less and less wired stuff whereas it's far more reliable.
My question is : Why should I buy wireless stuff instead of wired stuff ?

Comment: I think this is too subjective to comply to the FAQ.

Comment: Closed as per the FAQ: **Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!** Nothing to see here. Move along now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Wires are evil when it comes to portability

For best gaming experience you will use wired products.

But if you use your laptop on a regular basis and carry stuff around, cables tend to get in your way. And I tend to like heavier mice because they *feel* more right.

I use **[Microsoft Presenter Mouse 8000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/Presenter/productdetails.aspx?pid=085)** with great pleasure because it has presentation capabilities. I wouldn't change it for anything less. And who would've thought... Despite it's size it's comfortable and rather ergonomic. I was astonished myself as well.

And when buying wireless products you keep batteries in mind and have alčready decided to keep an extra pair at hand all the time. One of the good things is that my particular mouse doesn't drain them as quickly as I though it would. I probably use 2-3 pairs a year depending on use. But it's true I never forget to switch it off when I stop working.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer: when using HTPC or other combination that requires you to be far away from the computer.

Also, some people care about aesthetics more than they do about functionality.